# How to set the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environmentVariable in the WEBROOT (web.config) with APPCMD.exe?

Tags: iis, configuration, environment-variables, web.config, appcmd

How am I able to set the sites *web.config* "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" environmentVariable with APPCMD.exe?

So far I've tried ending it using `/commit:MACHINE/WEBROOT`, `/commit:webroot` and I get the below:

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/Help" -section:system.webServer/aspNetCore /+"environmentVariables.[name='ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT',value='Standalone']" /commit:MACHINE/WEBROOT
ERROR ( message:Configuration error
Filename: \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Help\web.config
Line Number: 0
Description: The configuration section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
. )
```

However I can update the "*applicationHost.config*" using the same code as below but a different `/commit`. I don't want to update the "APPHOST" though as I need to do the "*web.config*", which is where the value already is that I need to update:

```
set config "Default Web Site/Help" -section:system.webServer/aspNetCore /+"environmentVariables.[name='ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT',value='Standalone']" /commit:apphost
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/aspNetCore" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/Help" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. First you have to realise the areas that this can be committed to. I found it at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe and these are the below which I needed to use the "URL" section:

**url** — same as default; write configuration at the level for which it is set

**site** — write configuration in the Web.config at the site root of the url for which it is set

**app** — write configuration in the Web.config at the app root of the url for which it is set

**apphost** — write configuration at the server level, in the applicationHost.config file

As our software was was putting a default variable in, I had to first clear it with:

```
"%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe" clear config "Default Web Site/My_Site" /section:system.webServer/aspNetCore /commit:url
```

To the add the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

```
"%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site/My_Site" /section:system.webServer/aspNetCore /+environmentVariables.[name='ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT',value='Production'] /commit:url
```